# React-Native Controlled Modal Freezing

Tags: react-native

Disclaimers: 
Only can test on iPhone emulator atm. 
React-Native 0.49
Mac OSX High Sierra

I want to create a modal which gets its props from a parent component.
As below:

```
const Modal = ({ showModal, closeModal }) => (
  <Modal
    animationType="slide"
    transparent={false}
    visible={showModal}
    onRequestClose={() => {alert("Modal has been closed.")}}
    >
   <View style={{marginTop: 22}}>
     <Text>Hello World!</Text>
     <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => closeModal() }>
        <Text>Hide Modal</Text>
     </TouchableHighlight>
   </View>
  </Modal>
);
```

This is the parent example:

```
<View>
  <Modal
    showModal={this.state.showModal}
    closeModal={() => this.setState({ showModal: false })}
  />
  <ScrollView>
      {elements.map(element => {
        return (
          <Card key={element.id}>  
            <Badge onPress={() => this.setState({ showModal: true })>
              <Text>Show</Text>
            </Badge>
          </Card>
        );
      })}
  </ScrollView>
</View>
```

When I click the show modal button the modal pops-up as expected but when I click closeModal then the modal disappears and reappears again but this time I cannot interact with it, the UI seems as if it is frozen, I have to then restart the emulator.

If I copy and paste the code straight from the React-Native docs:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html
The modal works fine. It is a self-contained component though.

Any help/advice would be much appreciated.

Regards,
Emir

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After painfully rebuilding the component from scratch I see there was a unsuspected culprit:

```
componentWillUpdate() {
    UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental && UIManager.setLayoutAnimationEnabledExperimental(true);
    LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut();
  }
```

When I removed this code the modal worked fine but when I added it back it froze when I tried to close. This seems to be some animation conflict in iOS cant confirm for Android.

When I added a timeout of 1000ms the screen revealed a little more before it froze again.

So for now if someone has the same issue look for multiple animations being called.

Hope this helps someone, and if you have a better way of solving it please do let me know.

Regards,
Emir

Comment: This is still an issue for Android, but no longer seems to freeze up modals in iOS (as of react-native 0.59 for sure).  I found that `LayoutAnimation` needs to be completely omitted for the a Modal to work on android.

Answer (score 3):

This is a know issue and nothing to do with your code.

See here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16895

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that your `<Modal/>` is wrapped in a `<View/>`.

Comment: Why is this? Could you add more info?

Answer (score 1):

Very late, but issue still exist in latest version, And only solution i found is make different views in render method.

one for modal and one for other component.

```
render() {
    if (showErrorModal) {
      return (
          <ModalError message={message} visible={showErrorModal} handleBack={this.handleBack} />
      );
    }

    return (
        <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <View style={{ padding: 10, paddingVertical: 20 }}>
            {!active ? this.fieldlabel() : this.fieldSelect()}
          </View>

        // remove this one, do not use here. it will block the UI
        {* <ModalError message={message} visible={showErrorModal} handleBack={this.handleBack} /> *}
        </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Parent component, create a function will set `showModal` to `false`.

**Parent**

```
closeModal = () => {
  this.setState({
    showModal: false
  });
}
```

Then you need to pass it down to your `Modal`, via props.

`<Modal showModal={this.state.showModal} closeModal={this.closeModal} />`

Inside of your `Modal`, change:
`<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.closeModal() }>`

To:
`<TouchableHighlight onPress={closeModal}>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have done the above and I get the same behaviour, as the modal closes another one opens up and then I cannot interact with the UI.

I added the change <TouchableHighlight onPress={closeModal}>.

Answer (score 0):

Why do u use this.closeModal()? Use the one u are getting from the props,i.e just closeModal().

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => closeModal() }>
```

Comment: My mistake, I am doing onPress={() => closeModal() }, just didn't write it out on the example properly. Fixed it now.